# Editing text generated by WooCommerce

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

First time to ask a question here.. I searched and searched for the answer but it's a pretty niche question and difficult to google, so here I am.

I have a wordpress theme using woocommerce and in the "cart" page there is a section at the bottom left that calculates the cart totals. Underneath this section is a portion of "fine" print that says "Note: Shipping and taxes are estimated (taxes estimated for the United States (US)) and will be updated during checkout based on your billing and shipping information."

I'm looking for the correct file to edit this piece of text, basically I want to remove the "(US))" portion. I have searched through the plugins directory and many of the theme and woocommerce javascript and css files but haven't been able to find where/how this is generated.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be the path

```
/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/cart/totals.php
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the location in WooCommerce->Settings->Base Location. Alternatively you can use the following command in linux to find a string in a load of documents.

```
grep -rnw 'directory' -e "pattern"
```

Comment: See @Pwner answer for the exact location. The above should help you out in the future though.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the template files might cause you issues if/when you upgrade Woocommerce.  I'd recommend putting a filter in your theme's functions.php file.

I think the filter hook might be 'woocommerce_after_cart_totals' but you'll have to test it out to find the correct output.

Here's a primer on Woo filters & actions:

http://docs.woothemes.com/document/introduction-to-hooks-actions-and-filters/

And here's a list of all the actions & filters available:

http://docs.woothemes.com/document/hooks/